# Black Tint on Image Without Overlay - Firefox

Tags: css, svg, webkit, image-manipulation

I have successfully been able to tint my images in Safari using the following code:

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale; /*sepia, hue-rotate, invert....*/
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
```

However, it doesn't work in Firefox. I understand how to get the image fully grayscale in Firefox, but I don't want it to be fully grayscale -- instead a black tint like I was able to achieve with the above code in Safari.

Thank you <3

Comment: Hi @RachelGallen, Thank you so much for your help. The only thing is...with the code you provided, I can alter grayscale but it doesn't appear to work for brightness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
img { filter: grayscale(.5); filter: brightness(.5); }
```

in Firefox

for more examples see the [Mozilla guide to filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: you can fiddle with how 'gray' you want

Comment: 1.0 is fully grayscale and .5 is semi-grayscale

Comment: Hi @RachelGallen, Thank you so much for your help. The only thing is...with the code you provided, I can alter grayscale but it doesn't appear to work for brightness.

Comment: did you increase the brightness a bit? to maybe .7?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out.  img {
  filter: grayscale(.5); filter: brightness(.5);
}

Comment: ; is not a valid separator, just use a space. filter: grayscale(.5) brightness(.5);